# Sentinel value with while looping

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, sentinel

I am brand new to Java and am taking my first class. I've been struggling to do this homework assignment for the last two weeks and need some help. The assignment is to write a payroll program that prompts for pay rate and hours. It needs to loop continuously until I enter a sentinel value. Once the sentinel value is entered, it will average out the gross pay for me.

I've finally got it to where it will continuously loop, asking for pay rate and hours. It calculates income correctly and will loop.

Here is my problem. I can't seem to get the sentinel value of -1 to work. When I try to set it so that it will end when I enter -1, it doesn't do anything. It is also averaging the income after each set of pay rate and hours are entered. I want it to wait until the end and average all the income afterwards.

Please, any input would help!

Here is what I have so far. I am pulling from an implementation file to a test file.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PayRoll 
{
    private double hours;
    private double payRate;
    private double grossPay;

    public void Payroll()
    {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.payRate = payRate;
    }

    public void setHours (double hours)
    {
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    public double getHours ()
    {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setPayRate (double payRate)
    {
        this.payRate = payRate;
    }

    public double getPayRate ()
    {
        return payRate;
    }

    public double getPay()
    {
        return (payRate * hours);
    }

    public void calcPay()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double total = 0;
        int payCounter = 0;

        System.out.printf("Enter employee payrate: $");
        setPayRate(input.nextDouble());

        System.out.printf("Enter employee hours worked: ");
        setHours(input.nextDouble());

        double payRate = getPayRate();

        while (payRate != -1) //Loops until the sentinel value is read. 
        {
            if (getHours() > 40)
            {
                System.out.printf("Total income is: $%.2f",
                        ((getPayRate() * 40)+((getHours() - 40)
                        * (getPayRate() * 1.5))));
                grossPay = ((getPayRate() * 40)+((getHours() - 40)
                        * (getPayRate() * 1.5)));

                payCounter++;
            }

            if (getHours() == 40)
            {
                System.out.printf("Total income is: $%.2f", ((getPayRate() * 40)));
                grossPay = ((getPayRate() * 40)); 

                payCounter++;
            }

            if (getHours() < 40)
            {
                System.out.printf("Total income is $%.2f%n",
                        ((getPayRate() * getHours())));
                grossPay = (getPayRate() * getHours());
                payCounter++;
            }

            if (payCounter!= 0)
            {
                total = total + grossPay; //Adds grade to total
                double average = (double) total / payCounter;

                System.out.printf(
                        "%n%nNumber of gross income entered: %d.%n%nTotal is $%.2f%n",
                        payCounter, total);
                System.out.printf("%nAverage income is: %.2f%n", average);
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("No pay rate entered.");
            }

            System.out.printf("%nEnter employee payrate: $");
            setPayRate(input.nextDouble());

            System.out.printf("%nEnter employee hours worked: %n");
            setHours(input.nextDouble());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You set the double payRate only once in the function calcPay, then loop on a condition which will not change (because you don't set it again).

Comment: Olivia, I think you want your calls to setPayRate() to be inside the loop.  Your averages are printing out all the time because your payCounter is never 0.

Comment: Would I want to set a double payRate within each set of braces and also do a setPayRate() within each braces?

Also... I changed it so the average would print if gross income ended up being -1 instead of payCounter != 0. It keeps counting properly, but the total income is only -1. It doesn't seem to be picking up any previously entered figures. 

I know I am missing something vital, but I can't pin point what it would be. Why are my values not sticking?

Comment: Whatever you are using as the loop condition must be changed inside the loop in order for the loop to end. I think the simplest thing is to remove the local variable payRate and just use the member value.